# what is a "positive" synonym for 'target'?

Tags: synonyms, single-word-requests

e.g.: I was a(n) _____ to/of his kindness.

**Not** 'object'.

Comment: Excuse me, but the question asks for a "synonym".  The best answer below is "focus". I was going to offer "bull's-eye".  You might want to rephrase the question. Who on this English language website is voting for "beneficiary" as a synonym for "target"? Just pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a ***focus*** of his kindness. From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus):

> ***[focus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus)***
>
> 1. a. a center of activity, attraction, or attention
>      *the focus of the meeting was drug abuse*
>      *put immigration into focus as a hot topic for commentators*

Answer (score 5):

from the iWeb Corpus: I was a beneficiary of his kindness.

Answer (score 2):

I would use **recipient**.

For instance, from ["Affection—Expressions of Affection](http://family.jrank.org/pages/49/Affection-Expressions-Affection.html)":

> Public praise or admiration of the spouse, even if it is not said directly to the spouse (either it is overheard or relayed by a third party), enhances the feelings of love felt by the recipient.

And from ["The 5 Love Languages"](https://experiencelife.com/article/the-5-love-languages/):

> The husband’s compliments are sweet, and the mom’s presents are thoughtful, but because the intended recipient doesn’t send and receive love in the same primary way, the gestures fall flat.